# Launcher High Memory Usage

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, launcher, install4j

I'm using Install4j and Install4j Launcher to create .exe files for windows computers.
This works great, however, it is using 200MB RAM (taskmgr). Executing the same application directly via the jar package consumes 100MB Ram only!

Is there a hidden option that I have to change - do I have to modify my application, so it is more efficient?

Comment: The memory usage will mainly depend on the -Xmx and -Xms flags, the memory consumption of the install4j launcher is negligible.

Comment: An alternative to creating an EXE is installing an app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  The memory requirements of the app. can be set in the `j2se` element of the [`resourcces` section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources) of the launch file.  The example shown in the docs. is `<j2se version="1.3" initial-heap-size="64m" max-heap-size="128m"/>`.  Even better, JWS is supplied by Oracle and works on Windows computers (& OS X & *nix).  :)

Comment: IngoKegel: This looks very good already. I could reduce the usage from 210Mb to 140Mb.
AndrewThompson: Thanks, I already knew Java Web Start and used it for quite a long time. It couldn't convince me, however.